# How can i make this query/consultation?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm trying generate an query that returns a table like this one (only one occurrence of each version, eg. Windows 7)

[image]

But, i'm only can generate this (multiple occurences for the same version, eg. Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 7 Home, ...)

[image]

and this is the code that i'had

```
SELECT osname as 'Sistema Operativo' , count(osname) as 'Total UC',
COUNT(CASE WHEN TAG = 'VREG-DI' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'VRA-BIB' 
from hardware h, accountinfo 
where h.ID = accountinfo.HARDWARE_ID
group by osname
```

I want to add all "Windows 7 Enterprise/Starter/..." under the name "Windows 7".

This generates de table 'Hardware'

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hardware` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`DEVICEID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`WORKGROUP` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`USERDOMAIN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`OSNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`OSVERSION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`OSCOMMENTS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`PROCESSORT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`PROCESSORS` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`PROCESSORN` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`MEMORY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`SWAP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`IPADDR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`DNS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`DEFAULTGATEWAY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`ETIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`LASTDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`LASTCOME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`QUALITY` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`FIDELITY` bigint(20) DEFAULT '1',
`USERID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`TYPE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`DESCRIPTION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`WINCOMPANY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`WINOWNER` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`WINPRODID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`WINPRODKEY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`USERAGENT` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`CHECKSUM` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '262143',
`SSTATE` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`IPSRC` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`UUID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`ARCH` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24661 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this the table 'accountinfo'

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accountinfo` (
`HARDWARE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`TAG` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'NA',
`fields_3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I like the part where there's two columns both consisting of numbers, but neither column is named or described in the screenshot, or the question.

Comment: can you provide what's in `hardware` and `accountinfo` tables?

Comment: Um, aren't they the same but with different numbers? I don't see what makes one wrong and the other one right.

Comment: What column headers do the screenshots have Rod, because from our perspective you are already returning a table which has the same data...

Comment: No pictures please. Just proper DDLs and a desired result.

Comment: You'll need to figure out what depicts an OS "grouping" and what the logic is behind it, as it will likely be different for different OSes.  I noticed "Miscrosoft Windows Server" which seems to be much more broad than the other grouping, as there's 2003, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, etc but they're all lumped into one?   The apparent cut off for windows is "Miscrosoft Windows %", mac is Mac, how are you determining linux?  There a *ton* of linux distros, not all with linux in the name

Comment: Surely 'OS Name' and 'OS Version' should provide the grouping you need. OS: `Wincrosoft Windows` Version `XP` should be in the database. Maybe it should be `Major Ver` and `Minor Ver`. I think you'll need to clean up the data here because you've grouped them into versions that you didn't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
osnamez = CASE WHEN PATINDEX('Windows' + '7',osname) > 0 THEN 'Windows 7'
 ELSE osname
```

Self-explaining.

Checking if the content of the results has Windows 7 in it's name then it will just echo Windows 7

another soluton:

PHP:

```
if(preg_match('/^[windows 7]*$/', $row['osname?'])) 
$row['osname?']= "Windows 7";
```

^Not sure if this is the one
but just check

```
preg_match
```

there's one for it.

Comment: Thank, i make this to solve my problem and.. it works!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Write a formula on SQL to retrieve only the part of the operation system that is relevant create a new field in you query and group by it.

2) Create a new table with two columns: OS real name, and OS group name like this:

```
RealOSName                         OSGroupName
--------------------------------   -----------------------
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional   Windows 7     
Microsoft Windows 7 Home Basic     Windows 7
Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium   Windows 7
```

And group your query by OSGrupName (Best choise for me)

Comment: You don't need to change the tables. You only need to add a new one to group SO names.

Answer (score 1):

I like ericpap's second suggestion, though I would take it in a slightly different direction if possible by adding an additional column to your hardware table "osGroup" or similar

```
osGroup table
-----
groupId int primary key identity
groupName varchar(100)
```

so it could be populated with data like:

```
groupId    groupName
-----
1          Windows 7
2          Windows 8
3          Linux
4          Mac
```

etc

then your hardware table would look like (several columns snipped

```
osName                                osGroup
-------
Mac OS X                              4
Miscrosoft Windows 7 Professional     1
```

etc

That would make the answer to your specific question (or at least close to it - I'm not familiar with the deprecated comma join syntax):

```
SELECT groupName as 'Sistema Operativo' , count(groupName) as 'Total UC',
COUNT(CASE WHEN TAG = 'VREG-DI' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'VRA-BIB' 
from hardware h, accountinfo
inner join osGroup o on h.groupId = o.groupId 
where h.ID = accountinfo.HARDWARE_ID
group by groupName
```

With this method you will have the challenge of populating your data with the appropriate group, though it is more normalized.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you hope to get as an answer then.  Your data is not in a form that can be used in the way you want it.  You have the information available to you to **make** the data in a form you want, but are unable to do so.